# assign group id to rows with same value in specific columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
merchant | id    | Address
A        | 1     | aaa   
B        | 2     | bbb   
B        | 3     | bbb   
C        | 4     | ccc   
C        | 5     | ccc   
C        | 6     | ccc
```

Since same merchant can have different ids, I want to group the merchants by "merchant" and "Address", add a column with group id so entries in "merchant" that have the same group id are actually one merchant. Desired result like this:

> ```
> merchant | id    | Address |grp_id
> A        | 1     | aaa     |a1
> B        | 2     | bbb     |a2
> B        | 3     | bbb     |a2
> C        | 4     | ccc     |a3
> C        | 5     | ccc     |a3
> C        | 6     | ccc     |a3
> ```

Can some one help me with this?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: And why isn't `merchant` sufficient for this purpose?  It seems entirely redundant with `grp_id`.

Comment: sorry I didn't make this clear, I want to add this table later with another table which has  same columns and an extra "grp_id" column.

Comment: Can a merchant have multiple addresses? Would {Merchant1, Address1} and {Merchant1, Address2} have different id's?

Comment: @Error_2646  a merchant only have one address

Comment: @efsee So you just want to create a surrogate value for merchant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the Dense_Rank() window function to achieve this:

```
    SELECT "Id", "Merchant", "Address",
    concat('A', cast(DENSE_RANK() OVER ( order by "Merchant" ) As Varchar(10))) as Grp_id
    FROM "Table"
    ORDER BY "Id";
```

[image]